# Reordering text inside the brackets

Tags: perl

I have morphological parse tree in following way, where prefix, stem and suffix are labels and  other part is the changing I need to re order the in a way that prefix, stem  and suffix at beginning. For instance, 
 `(S (un:prefix) (sold:stem))` needs to be converted to    `(S (prefix:un) (stem:sold))`. Similarly, `(S (S (in:prefix) (decipher:stem)) (able:suffix))` to `(S (S (prefix:in) (stem:decipher)) (suffix:able))`. **It is also important keep the structure also.**

My perl code also:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'reduce';

while ( <> ) {

    my ($word, $ss) = / \( ( [^()]* ) \) /gx;

    my @ss = split ' ', $ss;

    my $str = reduce { sprintf 'S (%s) (%s)', $a, $b } @ss;

    printf "%s (%s)\n", $str, $word;
}
```

It doesn't do the intended task. What is the problem there ?

Comment: `$str=~s/\(([^\(\)]*)\:([^\(\)]*)\)/\($2\:$1\)/g;`

Comment: `perl -pi -e 's/\(([^(]*):([^)]*)\)/\($2:$1\)/g' input.txt` where input.txt is your file with these lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct on your question simple regex can replace the suffix and prefix.

```
my $str ="(S (un:prefix) (sold:stem))
(S (S (in:prefix) (decipher:stem)) (able:suffix)) ";

$str=~s/\(([^\(\)]*)\:([^\(\)]*)\)/\($2\:$1\)/g;

print "$str\n";
```

Output:

```
(S (prefix:un) (stem:sold))
(S (S (prefix:in) (stem:decipher)) (suffix:able))
```

Comment: use File::Slurp;
$str= read_file('test.ptb');
$str=~s/\(([^\(\)]*)\:([^\(\)]*)\)/\($2\:$1\)/g;

print " $str\n"